# Error de sintaxis al intentar insertar datos a MYSQL con php

Tags: php, html, mysql, innodb

Al intentar insertar los parámetros de "Usuario" y "Contrasena" extraidos de un formulario HTML me salta un error de Sintaxis de mySQL.

---

Este es mi código a la hora de insertar mi código

```
    require_once ('Conecction.php');
try {
// Iniciar la conexión a la base de datos
    $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=$db_host;dbname=$db_name;charset=utf8", $db_user, $db_pass);
// Asginar el modo de error Silencio para chequear nosotros mismos los errores
    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_SILENT);
// Asignar la codificación de caracteres a UTF-8
    $pdo->exec("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
// Insertar los datos con parámetros preparados
// bindParam para asignar valores en el momento de la ejecución
    $db_sentence = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO ' . $db_table . ' (nombre,password)
                                 VALUES ( :nombre, :password');
    $db_sentence->bindParam(':nombre', $nombre, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $db_sentence->bindParam(':password', $password, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $db_sentence->execute();
```

---

Esto es "Conecction" donde declaro mis variables para la base de datos.

```
<?php
$db_host = 'localhost';
$db_user = 'root';
$db_pass = '';
$db_name = 'Juanjo';
$db_table = 'Persona';
$db_sentence = '';
$db_error = '';
?>
```

---

Aquí es donde extraigo los datos del formulario.

```
if(isset($_POST['nombre'])==false || $_POST['nombre'] == ''){
    $nombre='No se ha introducido nada';

}else{
    $nombre=trim(strip_tags($_POST['nombre']));
}


if(isset($_POST['password'])==false || $_POST['password']==''){
    $password='No se ha introducido nada';

}else{
    $password=trim(strip_tags($_POST['password']));
}
```

El error que me da es "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 2"

Comment: podrías pegar el error de sintaxis que te da en mysql para poder ayudarte mejor

Comment: Es lo que dije, simplemente me da un error de Sintaxis.

Comment: si, pero ese error dice algo o no? porque podemos ver tu código, pero seria mas rápido saber el error que te esta dando mysql

Comment: Lo he puesto arriba. No lo puse porque no es nada descriptivo

Comment: error mio no vi el mensaje en la ultima linea!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a primera vista me parece que estas cerrando mal la sentencia

```
 $db_sentence = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO ' . $db_table . ' (nombre,password)
                             VALUES ( :nombre, :password');
```

si te fijas la comilla simple esta dentro del parentesis y no fuera del parentesis, asi:

```
 $db_sentence = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO ' . $db_table . ' (nombre,password)
                             VALUES ( :nombre, :password)';
```

Comment: Vaya, eso parecía ser el error. Muchas gracias.